# How to read text from hidden element with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

I'm trying to read the example String `1000` out of a hidden `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="hidden_div" style="visibility:hidden">1000</div>
```

I am aware that `WebElement.getText()` does not work on hidden elements in Selenium 2 (WebDriver), so I searched for solutions ([like this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webdriver/U-TAff1emvo)) and apparently the following code should work:

```
WebElement hiddenDiv = seleniumDriver.findElement(By.id("hidden_div"));
String n = hiddenDiv.getText(); // does not work (returns "" as expected)
String script = "return arguments[0].innerText";
n = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, hiddenDiv);
```

But it doesn't work for me, the variable `n` always ends up as `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EDIT: Oh this works.

```
String script = "return document.getElementById('hidden_div').innerHTML";
```

In firefox.

And so does this.

```
String script = "return arguments[0].innerHTML";
```

I tried as well but it does not seem to work with pure Javascript. Start the browser with 
Jquery as mentioned here. [How to use JQuery in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235013/how-to-use-jquery-in-selenium) and use following code for script.

```
String script = "return $('#hidden_div').text();";
```

This works.

Comment: According to the Selenium WebDriver FAQ: ": Why is it not possible to interact with hidden elements?
A: Since a user cannot read text in a hidden element, WebDriver will not allow access to it as well.

However, it is possible to use Javascript execution abilities to call getText directly from the element..."

I ended up using jQuery as well since my app is built on jQuery. Not sure if I agree with the reasoning behind this decision expressed in the FAQ, but at least there is a way to get at hidden text.

Comment: In older Selenium versions (at least 2.25), it was possible to get the text of a hidden element. In newer versions (at least 2.39), `getText()` returns an empty string if the element is not visible. This is in both cases different from the behavior when interacting with hidden elements. If you try to execute `click()` or `sendKeys(...)` you'll get an ElementNotVisibleException.

Comment: Just for completeness: The WebDriver FAQ can be read under https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions .

Comment: How do I do this on `python` selenium?

Comment: @TimBüthe Thanks, this explains why an old test fails :)

Answer (score 116):

Might be useful as well:

In some cases, one may find it useful to get the hidden text, which can be retrieved from element's `textContent`, `innerText` or `innerHTML` attribute, by calling `element.attribute('attributeName')`.

`element.getAttribute("textContent")` worked for me.

See more details there -> 
http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Woe, this is the answer folks!  I was about to do the javascript in the accepted answer above, but tried this, and works perfectly.  Much cleaner.

Comment: element.getAttribute("textContent").trim() gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: Good answer! I had better luck with innerText than textContent, because innerText combines multiple newlines and whitespace into one single space, while textContent doesn't.

Comment: Can confirm it still works in 2023. Way easier than trying to execute a script to pull the hidden text. This answer was incredibly helpful.

Comment: Works like magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Building upon the work of the already given answers, I created this utility method (Java). Maybe this is helpful for someone else.

```
public static String getText(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
    return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "return jQuery(arguments[0]).text();", element);
}
```

- I use [jQuery's text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to extract text nodes only. innerHTML would give you HTML tags as well.
- I use jQuery instead of $ in case of [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)
- don't manipulate the element or it's visibility

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        WebElement hiddenElement  = GET YOUR ELEMENT HERE;
        String hiddenContent= hiddenElement.getAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be any different to the answer from user3152984 https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475546/566763

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to use:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)hiddenDiv;
String n=(String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('hidden_div').value;");
System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem of reading invisible elements but I wanted back a WebElement object to do further parsing (not just its text).

This bit of code fulfilled my requirement.

```
(WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].style[\"display\"] = \"block\";"+
    "arguments[0].style[\"visibility\"] = \"visible\";"+
    "return arguments[0];", 
element);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm relatively new to Selenium (and to programming as whole), but I'm just sharing a solution that worked for me.*

Selenium 2 was not designed for handling elements with hidden visibility directly. You won't be able to find it's ID or CSS Selector, for example.

I had a situation with a bot where I had a HTML table with lots of itens, and when clicking when of them, a dropdown with hidden visibility openned. It was even in another frame.

It's a specific situation, but I couldn't find any solution, so I chose this (bad) one, but that works really consistently, despite the ugly code.

First you should `switchToDesiredFrame();`  -  enter your `driver.switchTo.frame()` logic here.

Than:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElements(By.tagName("table")).get(index_1);

List<WebElement> dataCells= table .findElements(By.tagName("td"));

WebElement spceificDataCellIWanted = dataCells.get(index_2);

System.out.println(spceificDataCellIWanted.getText());
```

The dataCells are literally the `<td>` tags, and they become `WebElements` in a list just as `<td>`'s are the elements in a list under the `<table>` "container".

It worked on Chrome and Firefox for me, but not on any headless browser, not sure exactly why. If you guys come across anything like that and have a more elegant solution (probably not so difficult to find it), please share!

Answer (score -2):

```
type='hidden'
```

When we come across any such case, first thing we should do is to try any action which doesn't make any change on that page, like drag etc, then do a frame switch.

Try a `getText()`, if that doesn't work, try the above as the 2nd alternative.