# Getting a hidden text from a HTML in JAVA using Selenium and WebDriver

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver, hidden-field

I'm trying to get a text from a html page which is into a hidden span.

```
<span class="hide"> Nike </span>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product-page.clearfix > .hide > span"));
String content = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
product.setBrand(content)
```

I've tried also with "`return arguments[0].innerHTML;`" and with "`element.getText()`"

I understood that I can use pure javascript, but this is a simple example, I need to use WebDriver and Java code for more complicated pages.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: package.driver.DhlWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read text from hidden element with Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047056/how-to-read-text-from-hidden-element-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to get a proper attribute like following:
 `element.GetAttribute("textContent");`
Should work well.
I guess getAttribute for JAVA - I work in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product-page.clearfix > .hide > span"));
String content = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", element);
System.out.println(content);
```

I'm using return `arguments[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

**I recommand to use:**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)element;
String content=(String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('hide').value;");
System.out.println(content);
```