# Extracting hidden element text in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to fetch the text "There are 4 products in your cart" in Selenium Webdriver using Java.

```
    <h2>
     <!-- Plural Case [both cases are needed because page may be updated in Javascript] -->
     <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt_s unvisible" style="display: inline;">
        There are 
        <span class="ajax_cart_quantity">4</span>
        items in your cart.
     </span>
     <!-- Singular Case [both cases are needed because page may be updated in Javascript] -->
     <span class="ajax_cart_product_txt " style="display: none;"> There is 1 item in your cart. </span>
     </h2>
```

I have tried using getText() and innerHTML but it hasn't worked.

Comment: use javascript... selenium interacts only with visible elements...

Comment: This could be an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047056/how-to-read-text-from-hidden-element-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below if it helps:

```
String text = "return $('.ajax_cart_product_txt_s.unvisible').text();";
```