# Is there another way to get the text from an element if it has no attribute and getText() returns a blank string?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The element in question is this:

```
<p class="boxMessage">Invalid credentials entered. Re-enter the required credentials.</p>
```

So far I've tried both getText() and getAttribute().

Comment: Is the element visible? If not, getText() would return nothing, but you can use a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047056/how-to-read-text-from-hidden-element-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `WebElement.getAttribute("value")`
or
you can also try the innerText attribute that will return the text content of an element.

```
 element.getAttribute("innerText")
```

or
You can also bring the element into the viewport by scrolling to it

```
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

and then try the `getText()` .

Comment: Thank you! element.getAttribute("innerText") worked.