# How to Scrape Text of Invisible Element in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my program I sometimes need to scrape text of invisible/hidden web element. I'm aware `WebDriver` normally returns visible text and that one could scrape hidden/invisible text via one of the following methods (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047056/how-to-read-text-from-hidden-element-with-selenium-webdriver) and [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/extracting-hidden-text-with-selenium) thread on SO):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
scrapedText = js.executeScript ("return arguments[0].innerHTML", webElement).toString();
```

Or by calling:

```
element.attribute('textContent')

element.attribute('innerText')

element.attribute('innerHTML')
```

While both of these solutions work, they will retrieve text that is not only invisible but is also normally not identified via `getText()` method. For example in the following HTML:

```html
<div class="a-section a-spacing-none">
<a id="brand" class="a-link-normal" href="/abc-d/b/ref=w_bl_sl_l_ap_ap_web_258XXX11?ie=UTF8&node=258XXX11&field-lbr_brands_browse-bin=abc+d">
<img id="brand" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/brands/byline-logo/25xxx11._CB520xxx1_SR120,50_.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>
```

`textContent, innerText or innerHTML` will all return `<img` element even though I'm trying to identify `'href'` attribute (using `XPath` '`//a[contains(@href, 'brands_browse-bin')]`' )

In other words, I'm trying to create a generic solution where my program will always identify invisible/hidden elements without identifying additional elements like it does when using  `textContent, innerText or innerHTML` (basically I want the same result as when calling `getText()` with the *only* exception that it includes hidden elements)

Is this possible?

Thanks

**Update:**

If you navigate to: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01H4LBIVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01H4LBIVC) and try to scrape 'price' (via `.//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']` for example) it will not work since the element is not visible (I'm aware I could make it visible by clicking 'One-time Purchase'). If I decided to retrieve element via one of the methods listed above - I would be able to retrieve the price but it would also retrieve the wrong value in the HTML sample provided above. If there's a method that identifies hidden elements (similar to `getText()` ) but does not automatically include "innerHTML" etc this issue would not be present. In short, I need a generic solution that will identify 'price' (which is hidden in above example) and also identify the correct element in the HTML snippet above.

Comment: Hi @S.O.S, can you try this code? `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("brand"));
  String scrapedText = js.executeScript ("return arguments[0].href;", element).toString();`

Comment: @AliCSE Thanks for your reply. This works, however I'm trying to create a generic solution where my program 1) Identifies both visible and non-visible elements 2) Solution works regardless of the specific HTML attribute. While the said solution works if attribute is 'href' it won't work when attribute changes. Basically, I want to identify exactly the same elements as with getText() but with added option of identifying hidden elements. Updating question w some additional details..

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave of retrieving the price from the Amazon product, the three options will all return the same value because there is nothing inside the element except text.

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price">$26.99</span>
```

The difference between those three options comes when there is formatting or other HTML elements inside. For example, if you use `.innerHTML` on the made up example HTML below

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><strong>$26.99</strong></span>
```

It would return `<strong>$26.99</strong>`, instead of just `$26.99`.

The simplest option (and the one you seem to want) is to always use `.textContent`. It will only return the contained text (never HTML tags, etc). At that point, it's up to you to properly provide a locator to find the element that contains the text you want.

There's a more in-depth explanation of the difference between the three (and others not mentioned) if you want more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032002/2386774).