# Wizmo5 flexgrid not rendering completely in browser when seeing through developer tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dom, coded-ui-tests, wijmo

Using coded-ui-tests to automate a screen which is using wijmo grid with scroll.
The problem is not able to record all the cells, as the cells which appear after scroll does not render in DOM, this is evident from Inspect element feature of browser.

How can I catch the cells?

Edited: The issue here is that only the cells which are visible is getting rendered in dom as we can see, while the part of the grid which is on right i.e. which will appear after scrolling is not getting rendered.

- The red line shows only the visible cells are rendered not the ones which are towards right of the grid.
- The yellow highlighted div shows the start of new row (which should not be in the actual case until all the cells of above row are not rendered).

[image]

Comment: Can you give a sample of the html for the wijmo?

Comment: Possibly [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) {UP} {DOWN} {LEFT} {RIGHT}

Comment: ok fine, I can do that but then it will capture every up,down,left,right separately, while i need to capture whole row at one go.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already maximized the browser window?

Comment: no its 100%, is there any property of wijmo which i can make use of so that it starts showing whole row in dom rather than only the visible part.

Comment: possibly need to run some [jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235013/how-to-use-jquery-in-selenium) to show the whole row by changing width and height

Comment: ok lloydm, as far as i know we can use codedui.jqueryextentions and then we can use like **EnableScript()** method...can you further explain memore about it.
Can i alter browser zoom anyhow ?

Comment: The best way is to try [jQuery](http://try.jquery.com/). altering the browser zoom will typically fail the coded ui test in error. 
$( ".wj-cell" ).css( "width: 1", "height: 1" );

Comment: ok, but bow iam able to get all the values in zooming in to an extent from where no scrolls are there....but that is happening in ie11

Comment: Wijmo Flexgrid has inbuilt virtualizatio and therefore, only visible cells are rendered in the DOM. This is the design behavior of the control in order to provide good performance. Else, if there are 10000 records in the grid and each is rendered then it would take a lot of time. You can display all the records by not setting the height of FlexGrid.

Comment: yeah that is why it doesn't render all the columns at once.Thanks.
I did a workaround for getting all column rendered.

Answer (score 1):

For record, Wijmo Flexgrid has inbuilt virtualizatio and therefore, only visible cells are rendered in the DOM. This is the design behavior of the control in order to provide good performance. Else, if there are 10000 records in the grid and each is rendered then it would take a lot of time. You can display all the records by not setting the height of FlexGrid.