# How to compare two grids on column values

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, coded-ui-tests, icomparable

We have two grids located one above other one, we need to compare the column values of the grids by using the column names.

[image: Grid with same column names]

I want to achieve the code in such a manner that:

```
//Comparing column value using column name.
if (Grd1Coll["PricingStream"].value == Grd2Coll["PricingStream"].value)
{
    //do this
}
else 
{
    //do this
}
```

What data structure like dictionary, hastable, hashset or etc. should I go for? Also, how can I make use of the `IComparator` interface here, if it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by _What data structure like dictionary,hastable,hashset etc i should go for_? Go for what? You already compare between them, now what do you want to do with that?

Comment: I still haven't decided which collection structure i should go for, which will be the best fit in this case hashtable,dictionary or anything else.

Comment: I'l ask again, go for what? What do you mean? Please be more clear with your question...

Comment: Is this a rehash of your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626780/wizmo5-flexgrid-not-rendering-completely-in-browser-when-seeing-through-develope?noredirect=1#comment47566067_29626780) ?

Comment: No, this is 1 step forward, iam getting all the grid data now,so i am looking for the best fit comparison.
We need to compare the column values of both the grids making column name as key so iam stumbling upon which collection object to use for this.

Comment: Why are you deciding how to compare them if the question of how to read in the values is not answered yet?

Comment: it's done, iam getting all the values now, i told u there.

Comment: In your example every call to a specific coulmn should return a collection of items, you expect them to be in a specific order?