# Using jQuery in Java - unknown error: $ is not defined

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

I try to use the following script code in my Java/Selenium function:

```
return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $(':animated').length").toString().equals("0");
```

But when I execute the code the following error comes up:

```
unknown error: $ is not defined
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `$` variable which normally contains jQuery is undefined. Have you included the jQuery library within the scope the JS code is being executed?

Comment: You mean I need a import statement for jquery?

Comment: I'm not familiar with selenium, so can't really guide you on that

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235013/how-to-use-jquery-in-selenium

Comment: The page you are running that command on does not have jQuery loaded. You either need to convert that command to JS (recommended) or load the jQuery library in the page.

Comment: How can I convert it in a JS command?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(":animated").length`.  also why are you doing that?  with selenium, you can just do `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(":animated")).length()`

Comment: Is this working with the jquery selector :animated? Your code gives me an InvalidSelectorException.

Comment: the selector @sircapsalot used is the one you provided in the question, so really if the selector is the issue then you need to provide some page source code!

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelector` inplace of `$`.

Your code would become

```
return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector(':animated').length").toString().equals("0");
```